# Verify youtube api v3 video exists JS

Tags: api, video, youtube, exists

I used the v3 API to check if a youtube video exists, however, I am not able to fetch the return data. I assume I need the

> "pageInfo": {
>     "totalResults": 1,
>     "resultsPerPage": 1
>    },

to check it. But how to get this information using the following code?

```
var data = $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=V2VmcuOEqEg&key={API-KEY-HERE}&part=status');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to determine if a video exists:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos";
var videoId = "id={YOUR-VIDEO-ID}";
var apiKey = "key={YOUR-API-KEY}";
var part = "part=snippet";

$.get(url + "?" + apiKey + "&" + videoId + "&" + part, function(response) {
    alert(response.pageInfo.totalResults);
});
```

`response.pageInfo.totalResults` will equal 0 if the specified video id does not exist and 1 if it does.

Comment: Wouldn't this expose your apiKey to the general public?

Comment: Yes - good point. If the code is being executed in a browser OAuth 2.0 would be a better route (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent). Best practice guide for securing API keys here: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037. If the call is being made on the server side (or for test purposes) then less of a problem. Only allowing referrals from domains that you own would also mitigate the risk.